# Java Web Service for .NET 2.0 Client on Linux (Fedora)

Tags: java, .net-2.0, service

I'm tasked with creating a Java Web Service for a .NET 2.0 client to consume.

What would your suggestions for the implementation be?

The solution doesn't need to be very heavyweight (don't need a full Java EE container I believe) but what do you think is the best solution for this? I have thought about using Glassfish v2 with JAX-WS annotations (@WebService), and JAXB XML Bindings(e.g. @XmlElement), which I assume the .NET client would be able to consume?

1. Has anyone tried this scenario?
2. Would Glassfish be overkill though, since I'm merely using the Web Service as a mechanism for .NET on Windows to communicate to the Linux box, the underlying application is extremely small.

Any suggestions are more than welcome :)

Thanks,

James

P.S. Other notes - would you use Axis/CXF instead of Glassfish? Would you use a servlet container such as Tomcat? etc.

Comment: Decided to try Tomcat and JAX-WS. Just needed to add the JAX-WS JARs to the lib folder, and that was that. Also works nicely over SSL. Next thing to try is WS-Security though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Axis2 and it works. 
I had the same problem of making Data Exposing API (Web Service in my case) in Java.

I made the web service using Axis2 and Spring (to access database) and the WSDL created via Axis2 was easily consumed via ASP.NET Application via its Add Web Service Dialog Box and the corresponding Proxy Classes were created easily.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, any particular reason why you chose Axis2?